# OAConsumer multi-part POST

Tags: objective-c, oauth, xauth

I am using the [Objective-C OAConsumer framework](http://code.google.com/p/oauthconsumer/wiki/UsingOAuthConsumer) to post to an OAuth/XAuth API and it is working really well to post basic strings, where I simply add an OARequestParameter. But I can't seem to find any reference to doing multi-part posts, where for instance image data is submitted along with the post.

Does anyone know if the Objective-C OAConsumer framework supports multi-part and how to do it?

Or, does anyone know of another way to do it still using XAuth to authenticate?